# How would you format the sending of a serial command from Android over bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

I have an iRobot with a RooTooth installed, which is a bluetooth to serial converter. It is said to operate just like a serial port and data should be received as such. I have been able to use a terminal program to send serial commands directly to it over a serial cable, and it works fine.

I can also use the app I have written to send commands from my phone to my computer which is monitoring incoming bluetooth commands, and it receives them exactly as intended.

However, when I send it from my phone to the rootooth, nothing happens. Is there something wrong about how I am sending the commands? Shown below is how I do it:

This is within a handler:

```
        case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
            ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            String s = "128 131";
            byte[] command = s.getBytes();
            connectedThread.write(command);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, 0).show();

            s = "137 0 100 128 0";
            byte[] command1 = s.getBytes();
            connectedThread.write(command1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, 0).show();
```

This is my write() function

```
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            Log.i(tag, "In write");
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
```

The issue must be formatting, no? Anybody with experience here, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Recently I have attempted this:

```
            String [] s = new String[2];
            s[0] = "128";
            s[1] = "131";
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
                byte[] command = s[i].getBytes();
                connectedThread.write(command);
                Thread.yield();
            }

            String [] t = new String[5];
            t[0] = "137";
            t[1] = "0";
            t[2] = "100";
            t[3] = "128";
            t[4] = "0";

            for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++){
                byte[] command = t[i].getBytes();
                connectedThread.write(command);
                Thread.yield();
            }
```

I have also tried this recent version including a "/n" string but that has not done anything either.

Comment: Does this really just take numbers with no newlines to terminate commands?  Even if it does, how is it going to discover the boundary between the final number group of one string and the first of the next?  Perhaps you need to at least insert a space?

Comment: When done in RealTerm which is a serial terminal program I simply type "128 131" (no parentheses), click 'Send Numbers', then "137 0 100 128 0" and click 'Send Numbers. I will try including a newline character though.

Comment: Are these supposed to be sent as binary values or as string representations of numbers?

Comment: I believe binary values. We have a C program which will send commands to the iRobot over a direct serial connection. This C program will take an array of ints [128, 131], break each int down into chars, and then sent the char[]. I have attempted to mimic this lately in my current code by having an array of strings ["128","131"], turning each string into byte[], and then send the byte[], but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else that happens to run into this problem, it turns out that a .write() from an OutputStream will take ints even though it says it will only take byte[]. Creating an array of ints for each command and sending them int by int ended up working. No need to include spaces or new lines.